# How to catch a "Done" key press from the soft keyboard

Tags: android

how do I catch specific key events from the soft keyboard?
specifically I'm interested in the "Done" key.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**Note:** This answer is old and no longer works. See the answers below.

You catch the KeyEvent and then check its keycode. FLAG_EDITOR_ACTION is used to identify enter keys that are coming from an IME whose enter key has been auto-labelled "next" or "done"

```
if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.FLAG_EDITOR_ACTION)
    //your code here
```

Find the docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html).

Comment: This answer lacks context unfortunately :(

Comment: Not valid answer anymore. Look at the most voted answer.

Answer (score 60):

I am not quite sure which kind of listener was used in the accepted answer.
I used the `OnKeyListener` attached to an `EditText` and it wasn't able to catch next nor done.

However, using `OnEditorActionListener` worked and it also allowed me to differentiate between them by comparing the action value with defined constants `EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT` and `EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE`.

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((actionId & EditorInfo.IME_MASK_ACTION) != 0) {
            doSomething();
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: For JellyBean and higher OnEditorActionListener is needed for this use case instead of OnKeyListener. From the docs: 


As soft input methods can use multiple and inventive ways of inputting text, there is no guarantee that any key press on a soft keyboard will generate a key event: this is left to the IME's discretion, and in fact **sending such events is discouraged**. You should never rely on receiving KeyEvents for any key on a soft input method.   Reference: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html

Comment: @JasonAxelson 's answer was the best

Comment: This line >> if (actionId & EditorInfo.IME_MASK_ACTION) << isn't valid Java expression, since what's in the brackets is not a boolean value. It won't even compile and I wonder how did this gain so much upvotes.

Comment: Both `OnEditorActionListener` and `OnKeyListener` ways worked for me.

Answer (score 42):

@Swato's answer wasn't complete for me (and doesn't compile!) so I'm showing how to do the comparison against the DONE and NEXT actions.

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView view, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        int result = actionId & EditorInfo.IME_MASK_ACTION;
        switch(result) {
        case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE:
            // done stuff
            break;
        case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT:
            // next stuff
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

Also I want to point out that for JellyBean and higher OnEditorActionListener is needed to listen for 'enter' or 'next' and you cannot use OnKeyListener. From the docs:

> As soft input methods can use multiple and inventive ways of inputting text, there is no guarantee that any key press on a soft keyboard will generate a key event: this is left to the IME's discretion, and **in fact sending such events is discouraged**. You should never rely on receiving KeyEvents for any key on a soft input method.

Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html

Comment: might also be worth returning true or false in the example

Answer (score 14):

just do like this :

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView view, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)
    {
       //Do Something
    }

    return false;
}
});
```

Answer (score 8):

```
    etSearchFriends = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSearchConn);
    etSearchFriends.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                Toast.makeText(ACTIVITY_NAME.this, etSearchFriends.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    });
```

Comment: how can i find keyCode for each and every key pressed from soft keyboard ??

Comment: @BhavanaVadodariya you can't. At least not on Jelly Bean. See: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html

Answer (score 3):

To catch a “Done” key press from the soft keyboard override Activity's onKeyUp method.
Setting a OnKeyListener listener for a view won't work because key presses in software input methods will generally not trigger the methods of this listener, this callback is invoked when a hardware key is pressed in the view.

```
// Called when a key was released and not handled by any of the views inside of the activity. 
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
            // code here
            break;
        default:
            return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for ;-) Works well even in every `EditText`! Thank you :-)

Comment: This is definitely the correct answer! Works Thanks alot.

Answer (score 2):

Note : inputtype mention in your edittext.

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/select_category" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:inputType="text" >

edittext.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

                if ((actionId & EditorInfo.IME_MASK_ACTION) == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                    //do something here.
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

you can override done key event by this method:

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            // do your stuff here
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

KOTLIN version:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_text" 
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:inputType="text" />
```

Do not forget to set **android:inputType.**

```
// Get reference to EditText.
val editText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edit_text)

editText.setOnEditorActionListener { _, actionId: Int, _ ->
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
        // Do your logic here.
        true
    } else {
        false
    }
}
```

Comment: Works as of 24-SEP-2021

Answer (score 1):

I have EditText that searches names, and it automatically shows results below in ListView. SoftInput keyboard only showed "next" button and enter sign - which didn't do anything. I wanted only Done button (no next or enter sign) and  also I wanted it when it was pressed, it should close keyboard because user should see results below it.

Solution that I found /by Mr Cyril Mottier on his blog/ was very simple and it worked without any additional code:
in xml where EditText is located, this should be written:
android:imeOptions="actionDone"

so hidding keyboard with Done button, EditText should look like this:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1central"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView2tie"
        android:ems="10"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:hint="@string/trazi"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />
```

Answer (score 0):

IME_MASK_ACTION is 255, while the received actionId is 6, and my compiler does not accept

```
if (actionId & EditorInfo.IME_MASK_ACTION)
```

which is an int. What is the use of &-ing 255 anyway? So the test simply can be

```
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView view, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)
    ...
```