# How to get focus on keyboard in android?

Tags: android

I am trying to get focus on first key of Android default keyboard (my target `API` is `10` and `version` is `2.3.4`). Or if it is not possible, can I atleast modify the sample keyboard and get focus on the first key there. In sample key board first key is 'Q.' Can anyone help with the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i do not know if this is gonna help you but it can get you on the right track maybe, you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031887/how-to-catch-a-done-key-press-from-the-soft-keyboard) out

Comment: I have tried many things. For instance using the sample key board, i tried to change the attributes, from hackers keyboard I tried to do the same. The problem is the focus is always on the editor. It never comes down to the keyboard. I am actually struggling with this issue for long time. any further help would be appreciated.