# Android NumberPicker widget, how to get value entered via softkeyboard?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, numberpicker

I'm having trouble getting the edit field of my `NumberPicker` to work properly, I've read several helpful answers to similar questions but none of them seem to address this particular issue.  Although the increment and decrement buttons do work correctly, if I enter a number using the soft keyboard I am unable to retrieve that value using the `NumberPicker.getValue()` method.  I've tried using my own `NumberPicker.OnValueChangedListener()` but it doesn't get called unless I click the up or down buttons, not when I press the soft keyboard Done button as some have suggested.  Can anybody help me with this?  Is this an Android bug?

Here is my XML layout:

```
<LinearLayout 
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/enter_nights_"
        android:layout_width="0dp" android:padding="10dip"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        ></TextView>
    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/numPick"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and my initialization code from my Activity onCreate():

```
    mNumNights = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numPick);
    mNumNights.setMinValue(1);
    mNumNights.setMaxValue(99);
    mNumNights.setValue(mNights);
    mNumNights.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
            // do something here
            Log.d(TAG, "Number of Nights change value.");
        }
    });
```

And on exit from the Activity I get the value like so:

```
            mNights = mNumNights.getValue();
```

I don't see any other methods in [Android NumberPicker documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html).  I did see a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14802869/catch-keyboard-done-for-numberpicker) suggesting hooking `onEditorActionListener()` to get the Done button, however this doesn't tell me how to get the value!  So, to sum up, my question is how do I get the value and why isn't the NumberPicker updating its value automatically?

Thanks!

EDIT: I stumbled across this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18944997/numberpicker-doesnt-work-with-keyboard#comment28781875_18944997) which is very similar to my question, the answers there look helpful although I'm hoping there is a better approach than suggested there.

Answer (score 22):

To have the activity pick up the edit, you need to call `nNumNights.clearFocus();` before calling `nNumNights.getValue();`. The call will update the control's value.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  I was encountering this issue when using a NumberPicker in a dialog.  If I hit the positive button in the dialog before hitting 'done' on the NumberPicker keyboard entry, the picker would return the previous value.  Clearing it's focus forced it to update and return the correct value without having to hit 'done' on the keyboard.